# 7-Zip. t (Test integrity of archive) command. Syntax. Two variants. Difference

Tags: windows, 7-zip, archiving, data-integrity, file-archiver

I use 7-Zip. I work in Windows 10 Home 64-bit. I use command line. From 7-Zip help I know there is t (Test integrity of archive) command.

Do I understand right way the following?

---

In this case

```
7z t archive.zip
```

I check integrity of zip file? I check just one file - zip file.

---

In this case

```
7z t archive.zip *
```

I check integrity of every file inside zip file? But I don't check integrity of zip file itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that both `7z t archive.zip` and `7z t archive.zip *` should do the exact same thing :

They test the integrity of 'archive.zip' *and* simulate the extraction of all of its contents.

A further test shows me that the same command, both with the asterisk (*) *and* without the asterisk, produced the exact same output, for both ZIP and 7Z files.

I think you should better omit the asterisk if you want to test a whole ZIP/7Z file and all of its contents (`7z t archive.zip`).

Please note that `*` and `*.*` are different !

[See also in this documentation](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/test.htm)